# jQuery: Select dynamic element on ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to select dynamically created `element` on `ajax success`, I have number of `check boxes` in a `table` & on `ajax success` I replace the `table` with new content which does not allow me to select any new `check box`. 
I know that we can use `jQuery` [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function to `trigger click` on dynamic `elements` but in my case I didn't need any `click event` just need to select that `element` & change the text on it.

Here is my Code.

```
$('#apply').click(function()
    {
      $('#loading-overlay-please-wait').show();
      var checkIds = $('#gridviewId').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
      var uncheckIds   = $( 'input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked):not(:first)' ).map(function() { return this.value; }).get();
      $.ajax(
      {
        'data':{checkedIds:checkIds,uncheckedIds:uncheckIds},
        'method':'POST',
        'url':'approve',
        'dataType':'json',
        'success':function(data)
        {

            if(data.status == 1)
            {
                $('#catalogResults').html(data.content);
                $( 'input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked):not(:first)' ).next('span').text(' Need Approval'); //This is not working on dynamic content
                $('input:checkbox:checked').next('span').text('Approved'); //This is not working on dynamic content

            }
             $('#loading-overlay-please-wait').hide();
             $('body').scrollTop(0);
        }

      })

    });
```

Answer (score -1):

`$('input:checkbox:checked')` this selector should `throw` `error`.Please check it and `jsfiddle` link for `code snippet` will be useful to `debug` further.